# Issue with component array filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to create multiple components and delete them by pressing on button click. I created the components. But i can't delete it.

```
state = {
    data: '',
    todoCard: [],
    id: 0

}

addCard() {
    var action = this.state.todoCard.concat(<TodoCard deleteCard={() => this.deleteCard(this.state.id)}
                                                      key={this.state.todoCard.length}/>);
    this.setState({id: Math.random() + 1, todoCard: [...action]})
}

deleteCard(id) {
    const cards = [...this.state.todoCard];
    const updatedList = cards.filter(item => this.state.id !== id);
    this.setState({todoCard: updatedList});
}
```

I wanted to give unique id to the Card component. But when i click one of cards' buttons,all of cards are gone.
I displayed the component array like this:

```
{this.state.todoCard
```

Comment: Are you able to post the code for the function "setState()"

Comment: I don't think we have enough to go on here, but try adapting this to your files: https://jsfiddle.net/rx7asojz/23/

Comment: @thatguytyler As it says in the tags, this is a [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) project, and as such [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is a known operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding of your question, and the portion of code you have displayed. You're trying to remove a "card" from your list of cards in state `todoCard`.

Your `todoCards` array contains components, you cannot interact with these attached components, the way you are attempted to since they do not have the attributes like the `id` you are trying to use to `filter`.

My suggestion is to store the data necessary to create your `TodoCard` components as an `object` or `Number` value in your `todoCard` array, rather than an array of components. Then you can more easily `filter` based on that data. When you go to render, you can map the data into components as show below:

```
import React from "react";


class TodoCard extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<div onClick={this.props.deleteCard}>{this.props.value}</div>);
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        data: '',
        todoCard: [],
        id: 0
    };

    addCard() {
        this.setState({
            id: Math.random() + 1,
            todoCard: [...this.state.todoCard, this.state.id]
        })
    }

    deleteCard(id) {
        this.setState({
            todoCard: this.state.todoCard.filter(item => item !== id)
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <button onClick={() => this.addCard()}>Add</button>
                {this.state.todoCard.map((e, i) => (
                    <TodoCard deleteCard={() => this.deleteCard(e)}
                              key={i}
                              value={e}/>
                ))}
            </div>
        );

    }
}

export default App;
```

---

Here is an implementation where each element in `todoCard` is an `object` instead of `Number`.

```js
import './App.css';
import React from "react";


class TodoCard extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<div onClick={this.props.deleteCard}>{this.props.value}</div>);
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        data: '',
        todoCard: [],
        id: 0
    };

    addCard() {
        this.setState({
            id: Math.random() + 1,
            todoCard: [...this.state.todoCard, {id: this.state.id}]
        })
    }

    deleteCard(id) {
        this.setState({
            todoCard: this.state.todoCard.filter(item => item.id !== id)
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <button onClick={() => this.addCard()}>Add</button>
                {this.state.todoCard.map(({id}, i) => (
                    <TodoCard deleteCard={() => this.deleteCard(id)}
                              key={i}
                              value={id}/>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```